# center first element of family tree design in top-center of page

Tags: html, css

I'm following a tutorial on building a family tree design with interactivity, the design and interactivity is great.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/goofy-sun-ke4bx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Link of article ( code inside ) [view link](https://www.iamrohit.in/javascript-css-horizontal-employee-treeview/)

Link of video ( how family tree looks ) [view link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwszcIQiIbw)

It works fine but, the tree designs always starts from top left corner. This is the css that does that:

```
.genealogy-body{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 50px;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

I have tried changing it to put it in center and open up the rest of the family tree design from the center, no success. It is plain css and should be as simple as that, anyone might know an alternative way to make it work?

Goal is: keep it the same way as it is, just do the family opening tree from the top-center of the page.

Comment: Could you save us some time by providing a Fiddle?

Comment: @phucbm of course, didn't think of that, thank you! will do right now

Comment: @phucbm just added a sandbox link, thanks for the reminder again!

Answer (score 0):

This might be solution of your problem

```
.genealogy-body{
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   padding: 50px;
   min-height: 500px;
   padding-top: 10px;       

   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: this works fine, but when the tree gets bigger and screen smaller, I cannot move the scrollbar to the left to view elements on the left. Any idea what can fix it?